# PHP - PHPSESSID spoofing

Tags: php, security, session

Ok I know successfully spoofing a PHPSESSID by guesswork is not a likely attack vector for even a very busy site.

But I am wondering if there are any measures PHP uses to block brute force guessing by recognising requests where the PHPSESSID does not exist.

And if not are there any PHP functions that can be used to recognise a session start that has been rejected due to a bad PHPSESSID?

Or are these attacks so unlikely that such measures are not necessary?

Comment: For example: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php

Comment: This is probably something you'd address with a [tag:fail2ban] rule rather than in application logic.

Comment: [The Fast Track to Safe and Secure PHP Sessions](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/04/fast-track-safe-and-secure-php-sessions)

Answer (score 0):

I would be of the opinion that, yes, "these attacks are so unlikely that such measures are not necessary."  In fact, they probably aren't "attacks" at all.

If I decide to eat dinner before responding to a web-site, and especially if I have a nice glass of wine with that dinner, then there's a *very(!)* good chance ... ahem ... that my session will have expired.  This isn't an "attack."

The session-ID "nonce" is fundamentally a *random* value, within a numeric space so vast that "brute-force" would never actually work.  The only credible "attack" would therefore be that a still-current ID would somehow be *stolen* by an evil-person who necessarily would be launching their legitimate attack from a *different* IP-address.  And, so far as I recall, the existing PHP session-handling logic already considers this.

*("Peanut Gallery™, please chime in here" – Does it?)*

Of course I am also presuming that you are in *complete* control of everything that is transmitted to the user's browser as part of "your" web-page.

Comment: I can be on wireless on my phone, start a session, disconnect from wireless and use cell data, and continue that session.  Where a client is coming from shouldn't matter.   For the OP, if this is a big issue, you may want to consider shortening the session lifetime

Comment: Well if PHP successfully checks the  IP of a PHPSESSID that would be enough I suppose.